# Duplicate CMake groups in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, duplicates

I have the following project structure:

```
test_project
│   CMakeLists.txt
|   main.cpp
```

In the main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

project("test_proj")

source_group("main_target" FILES "main.cpp")

add_executable(
    "test_exec"
    "main.cpp"
)
```

When I open the generated CMake buildsystem in Visual Studio I get duplicate `main_target` groups:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8jsU.png)

I've tried several combinations of passing source_group parameters, using PREFIX for example, and I get the same result. Or switching between generators such as `Ninja`, `Visual Studio 16 2019 Win64`, `Visual Studio 17 2022 Win64`, etc.

It's not a deal breaker, but I have several files in my main project and I want to put them in different groups. Seeing the same groups appear twice is irritating.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I used Visual Studio 2019 x64 and CMake 3.24.1 and the command line `cmake -S test_project -B test_project_build -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64`. Please clear your cmake build directory and retry.

Comment: Hello, having a main in a shared library seems antinomic. What will happen if you link your lib with another file that has already a main() function ?

Comment: @vre
Strange, I've tried to use "Visual Studio 16 2019" generator and have the same results.

With the following CMakeLists.txt:

``` cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project("test_proj")
source_group("main_target" FILES "main.cpp")
add_executable(
    "test_exec"
    "main.cpp"
)
```

Comment: @Martin

That's correct, it was only for the sake of demonstrating the problem. I will edit the original question to mention executable instead.

Comment: How are you generating the solution? With the command I provided or did you use a different command line? What is your CMake version?

Comment: @vre 
I generate it by opening the project folder in VS, which automatically starts the CMake generation.

After further investigation, I found out what is the problem. 

I've tried your CLI command too. Both this and VS generate a .sln file, and that's the thing I am supposed to open in VS.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bug. See the visual studio feedback item here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cmake-Duplicated-folderssource_group-/10133611